# Should I place a script partial on EVERY page, or in the Layout.cshtml partial file?

Tags: asp.net-core

My organization is currently working on a new ASP.Net Core web app. We have a couple of common Javascript functions that are used on all pages. At first we put the scripts in a partial file and started adding the following to the Scripts section on every page.

```
 @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_CompanyScriptsPartial"); }
```

At this point we have only added it to a small handful of pages, but have around or so left to add it to.

Is it better to add that on every single page, or can I just put the same code in the layout.cshtml (it works when I do it, I just don't know if I *should* do it)? What is the 'best practice' method for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the scripts are used on all of your pages, or even if they are used on most of the application pages, then it is better to add the script link to the layout.

This way you avoid duplicating code by not adding `RenderPartialAsync` to every page.

Best practice is not copy and paste code and to have a single location for common code.

Comment: Is the proper was with a RenderPartialAsync like I have it, or is there a better way?

Comment: It depends on what is in _CompanyScriptsPartial. If it is just a few links to .js files then they could be directly added to the layout. If it is a large amount of javascript then a separate partial is better like you have shown.

Comment: It is around 100 loves of course inside a script tag, with the possibility of growing. Sounds like it's best to have it in a separate file and include like I've shown. Thanks for the help.